# ASP MVC routing works differently in a subdomain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, subdomain

I have an application hosted on an Amazon server with two instances, one for test and one for production.

ie.
On server 123.456.789.123 the app instances are
 - wwwroot/myappuat
 - wwwroot/myappprod

So the subdomain myapp.mydomain.com DNS settings point to the server 123.456.789.123
And rewrite rules have been set for these instances, let's just look at production

```
<rule name="myapp.mydomain.com" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^myapp.mydomain.com$" />
</conditions>
<action type="Rewrite" url="\myappprod\{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

The trouble is when RedirectToAction seems to behave differently than when I was just testing on localhost in development.

For instance:

```
RedirectToAction("Login", "Home")
```

will redirect to http://myapp.mydomain.com/myappprod/Home/Login instead of the intended http://myapp.mydomain.com/Home/Login

I suspect I need to modify the routing settings in RegisterRoutes. But I don't know what to do.

Any help on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're not using MVC Routing.  You're using IIS Url Rewriting.  They're two totally different things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where I went wrong.

Tilda's.

For example there is a redirect from the URL authorization to the login page which was set like this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

Since the URL has been rewritten, the path still included /myappprod.
Removing the tilda fixed it

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/Home/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

One extra thing while I'm on here. Make sure you use `Url.Content("~/url/here")` not just `"~/url/here"`. Particularly with those tildas.

Comment: One extra thing while I'm on here. For MVC n00bs like me, make sure you use Url.Content("~/url/here") not just "~/url/here". Particularly with those tildas!

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the prefix in the RegisterRoutes method in global.asax

e.g.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "myappprod/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
```